# Tables: how to modify a single row vertical spacing

Tags: tables

I've got this table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \centering
      \setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
      \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
      \begin{tabular}{llr}
        &&\emph{What went wrong} \\
        {Info \#1:} & the first stuff & nothing \\
        Info \#2: & the other stuff & everything \\
      \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

But I want the first row to be close to the second one, as if it's "below aligned". Like this:

[image]

How to do it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try with `\\[-1cm]` at the end of the first line

Comment: Ya, it works. Thanks.